# An "Escalate to an Astronomer (in related field)" button?

Tags: discussion

In a comment under [this question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/16262/7982) I expressed "*I wish there was an* `Escalate to an Astronomer in a Related Field` *button, even if only for moderators*."

Is there any way I can try to improve the chance of someone knowledgeable in that field seeing that question and offering an answer or even a comment? An actual button would be quite an unusual feature request, I'm of course speaking figuratively.

I could edit the question once in a while to float it to the top of the recent activity stack, but besides that, anything else?

Related:

- [What can we do about the deteriorating quality of questions?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/246/7982) (Up-vote quality questions & answers - always.)
- [Balance between professional and enthusiast questions](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30/7982)
- [Let's ask more meaty questions!](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/59/7982)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way that Stack Exchange handles this is by with tags. You define the tags that appropriately match your question and hope that a knowledgeable person on, say meteorites, is watching the meteorites tag. It sounds like you want a personal button that will send your question directly to the relevant astronomer's inbox, which isn't really the point of this website.

Unfortunately, you have to contend with the astronomy stack exchange being a smaller group with not nearly as many eyes watching the questions as more popular sites like stack overflow. A relevant expert might not always be available to answer your question. You can't really get around that one.

Comment: It's been several years since I first asked this, and things seem to be going quite well actually! I was quite the SE noob then, I'm less of one now.